# rrd4j with java

Tags: java, rrd

I am currently developing a program with Java that collect and illustrate IP traffic from similar information and draw the graph of this information.
So I must use rrd4j rrd with java to save the data flow from a JTable in another table first and then use RRDTool to draw the graph .
but my problem is how to have the info stored in rrd and also how to create database RRD4J

thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would check [rrd4j](http://code.google.com/p/rrd4j/) project home page and check some documentation. On the main page there is usage example of how you create the database and I think it's quite clear and no needed to be explained, since it would be copy+paste.
Now what about storing the information.. First of all you need to define how much and what type of data you want to store. For example in the project I'm working, we are aggregating data daily, weekly, monthly and yearly. You also need to specify what is the frequence of data collection: because it really makes difference if it's 5 seconds or 5 minutes.
You should also have a look at former rrd project homepage and ganglia, the part where you defining the RRD files creation, it will really help you to understand how RRDTool and data storing works.

Comment: Im new to this site and i have been lookingfor insert in many other forum but i cant find what im looking for,so please help me!!                                              
My problem is in the update :
I have a JTable that display  IP traffic,i dont know how to save every row of the jtable in the RRD after checking in the rrd table(the rrd table is a Qualification of the different dataflow that is already exist in the database"rrd") to put it in the right flow?! if this explanation is not clear i can explain more